# Failed to send SSL Close message

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, message-hub, sslengine

I have a thread which once in a while is going to list the topics on the Message Hub. But once in a while, I am getting a :Failed to send SSL Close message.

Any ideas?

```java
KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(getConsumerConfiguration());
try {
    Map<String, List<PartitionInfo>> topics = consumer.listTopics();
    return new ArrayList<String>(topics.keySet());
} finally {
    if (consumer != null) {
        **consumer.close();**
    }
}
```

I am getting the warning from **consumer.close**.

The configuration of the consumer:

- sasl.mechanism = PLAIN
- security.protocol = SASL_SSL
- group.id = consumer1
- ssl.enabled.protocol = TLSv1.2
- ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = HTTPS
- ssl.protocol = TLSv1.2
- sasl.jaas.config = org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="USERNAME" password="PASSWORD";

> [WARN ] 2018-01-25 20:12:23.204 [ClusterChannelMonitorTaskThread]
>   org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer  {} - Failed to send
>   SSL Close message  java.io.IOException: Unexpected status returned by
>   SSLEngine.wrap, expected CLOSED, received OK. Will not send close
>   message to peer.  at
>   org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.close(SslTransportLayer.java:158)
>   [kafka-clients-0.11.0.0.jar:?]    at
>   org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.closeAll(Utils.java:663)
>   [kafka-clients-0.11.0.0.jar:?]    at
>   org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.close(KafkaChannel.java:59)
>   [kafka-clients-0.11.0.0.jar:?]    at
>   org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.doClose(Selector.java:582)
>   [kafka-clients-0.11.0.0.jar:?]    at
>   org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.close(Selector.java:573)
>   [kafka-clients-0.11.0.0.jar:?]    at
>   org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.close(Selector.java:539)
>   [kafka-clients-0.11.0.0.jar:?]    at
>   org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.close(Selector.java:250)
>   [kafka-clients-0.11.0.0.jar:?]    at
>   org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.close(NetworkClient.java:505)
>   [kafka-clients-0.11.0.0.jar:?]    at
>   org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.close(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:439)
>   [kafka-clients-0.11.0.0.jar:?]    at
>   org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.closeQuietly(ClientUtils.java:71)
>   [kafka-clients-0.11.0.0.jar:?]    at
>   org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.close(KafkaConsumer.java:1613)
>   [kafka-clients-0.11.0.0.jar:?]    at
>   org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.close(KafkaConsumer.java:1573)
>   [kafka-clients-0.11.0.0.jar:?]    at
>   org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.close(KafkaConsumer.java:1549)
>   [kafka-clients-0.11.0.0.jar:?]    at
>   com.ibm.saas.msg.kafka.KafkaMessageService.listChannelNames(KafkaMessageService.java:305)
>   [saas-msg-kafka-TRUNK-SNAPSHOT.jar:TRUNK-SNAPSHOT]

Comment: Looks like a bug in Kafka. The SSLEngine is a pretty difficult thing to drive correctly.

Comment: Filed a issue on Kafka: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-6510

Comment: The discussion there and at the other issue you linked doesn’t give much hope. They certainly didn’t understand the issue when the code was written.